# jdk source code lookup in cider not working

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I am using Emacs 26.3, CIDER 0.23.0 (Lima), Open JDK 11.0.5 (OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.5.10.2 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS) on macOS Mojave (10.14.6). My CIDER installation works for everything that I need, but not for referencing JDK source code and javadoc. It shows me Clojure source for Clojure methods but not JDK source for any Java methods for some reason. I figured out that my cider-classpath is missing the jdk source.zip location and other jars from JRE as seen below.

```
/Users/user/Projects/clojure/test/test
/Users/user/Projects/clojure/test/src
/Users/user/Projects/clojure/test/dev-resources
/Users/user/Projects/clojure/test/resources
/Users/user/Projects/clojure/test/target/classes
/Users/user/.m2/repository/cider/cider-nrepl/0.22.4/cider-nrepl-0.22.4.jar
/Users/user/.m2/repository/nrepl/nrepl/0.6.0/nrepl-0.6.0.jar
/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.0/clojure-1.10.0.jar
/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/spec.alpha/0.2.176/spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar
/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.specs.alpha/0.2.44/core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar
/Users/user/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.5/clojure-complete-0.2.5.jar
```

How can I make JDK source code lookup work in CIDER?

Comment: This used to work for me but it's not working anymore. It seems that the src.zip file is not on the classpath. May be related to an upgrade to Java versions higher than JDK 1.8. I've also tried setting the variable `cider-jdk-src-paths` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a directory containing a zip with Java sources as a resource to Leiningen profile (`~/.lein/profiles.clj`) e.g. a default one:

```
{:user {:resource-paths ["/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8"]}}
```

This now must be included in every project which activates the profile.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Emacs 26.3 CIDER 0.24.0 nREPL 0.6.0 Java 1.8.0_242.